# I am not able to add user input to state properly, getting map not a function error when it is

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list which is stored in the App component. This is used to display all the people and I want to be able to add new people to this list. I am not able to add input into my state, I am getting an error that map is not a function. Am i not creating the array properly?

```
const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Artos Hellas',
      id: 1
    }
  ]);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('');

  const handleNewName = event => {
    setNewName(event.target.value);
  };
  const addName = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const personObject = {
      name: newName,
      id: persons.length + 1
    };
    setPersons(persons.concat(personObject));
    setPersons('');
  };

  const rows = () => persons.map(p => <li key={p.key}>{p.name}</li>);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addName}>
        <div>
          name : <input value={newName} onChange={handleNewName} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <ul>{rows()}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `setPersons('');` statement, you might wanted to use `setNewName('')`:

```
const addName = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const personObject = {
    name: newName,
    id: persons.length + 1
  };
  setPersons(persons.concat(personObject));
  // setPersons('');
  setNewName('');
};
```

Also, you got a wrong `key` prop while rendering list elements:

```
//                                            v Not p.key
const rows = () => persons.map(p => <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>);
```

Moreover, it's confusing when you use a function named `row` and call it `row()`, you may try naming it as an action like `renderRows` or just use the `ReactElement` array:

```
const renderRows = () => persons.map(p => <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>);
<ul>{renderRows()}</ul>

// Or
const rows = persons.map(p => <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>);
<ul>{rows}</ul>
```